# WPF Prism DataGrid not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, prism

I've a problem with DataGrid in Prism MVVM.

When I edited entity in other window, then I create new window with DataGrid is not updated. Only run application again help. It's my code:

```
<DataGrid Name="ClientsTable" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfClients, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" Margin="22,10,22,55" Width="800"/>
```

Part of ViewModel for this window:

```
public ListOfClientsViewModel(IClientService clientService, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    this.clientService = clientService;
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    ListOfClients.AddRange(clientService.GetAllClientsForList());
}

private ObservableCollection<ClientForList> listOfClients = new ObservableCollection<ClientForList>();
public ObservableCollection<ClientForList> ListOfClients
{
    get { return listOfClients; }
    set { SetProperty(ref listOfClients, value); }
}
```

And part of model from collection. It's in other project.

```
public class ClientForList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string id;
    private string name;
    private string firstname;
    private string lastname;
    private string city;
    private DateTime createdDate;


    [DisplayName("Numer klienta")]
    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != id)
            {
                id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    [DisplayName("Nazwa")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != name)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    [DisplayName("Imię")]
    public string Firstname
    {
        get { return firstname; }
        set
        {
            if (value != firstname)
            {
                firstname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    [.....]

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And, when I edit entity in other window, then I open window with DataGrid by:

```
void ExecuteListOfClients()
{
    ListOfClients listOfClientsWindow = new ListOfClients();
    listOfClientsWindow.DataContext = new ListOfClientsViewModel(IClientService, EventAggregator);
    listOfClientsWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

And data in DataGrid is old. When I restart application data is actual. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
set { SetProperty(ref listOfClients, value); }
```

do

```
set { SetProperty(listOfClients, value); }
```

and instead of

```
ListOfClients.AddRange(clientService.GetAllClientsForList());
```

do

```
ListOfClients = clientService.GetAllClientsForList().ToObservableCollection();
```

You may need to implement the extension **ToObservableCollection()**. 
Another solution is to change the property ListOfClients  as a normal IList and then implment INotifyPropertyChanged inside your view model

Comment: `SetProperty(listOfClients, value);` won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved part of the problem.

I have cut the window creation without the manual creation of the ViewModel on:

```
void ExecuteListOfClients()
{
    ListOfClients listOfClientsWindow = new ListOfClients();
    listOfClientsWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

And in xaml ListOfClients.xaml I changed to:

```
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
```

And now, after reopening the window, it shows refreshed data;)

But there is still a problem. I've done the LoadData method, which is done in the constructor and assigns data to the ObservableCollection. It works. I have set a button for it and after editing the client I click to load new data and unfortunately nothing happens. In the future I want this method to be called from the EventAggregator after editing the client, but for now I have made a button to test and unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It works. The problem was not in the WPF itself, nor was the view strangely enough. The problem lay in EntityFramework. I had to modify the command choosing data from the database to the collection:

```
var clients = db.Clients.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```